# "half" or "half of"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> - The number of apples is **half** the number of pears
> - The number of apples is **half of** the number of pears

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct.

When translating words into symbols in an elementary algebra class the phrase "One half *of* a number" is translated as (1/2)x.